# Staging on heroku with different database than prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app that is running on a stand alone server and is using mysql. I would like to create a staging server that is running pg. Currently my Gemfile looks like...

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'

group :staging do
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

I'd like to just drop gem 'pg' into the staging group, but how do I designate heroku as staging. So when I push to heroku it knows to grab the pg file from the staging group and not the root of the Gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more important thing is your `config/database.yml` file. You should be able to have both gems installed (unless they have non-compatible dependencies), but specify the postgres adapter and connection settings under the staging environment.

If you only want one of the two gems installed in a given environment then put the `mysql2` gem inside a `production` group, and the `pg` gem in a `staging` group.

Comment: Well duh! Did not even think to just add both the mysql and pg gems at the root of the Gemfile. Thanx!

Comment: Hey, we all do silly things from time to time. :) Thanks for the accepted answer.